# LayerList in WebMap

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to create a map app with [ESRI calite-maps](https://github.com/Esri/calcite-maps).

Can somebody tell me how to integrate the LayerList widget (bottom-right) inside the Layers panel (top-right)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating your layerlist, you can designate the html element in which it will be placed by using the [container](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-BasemapToggle.html#container) property like so:

```
var layerList = new LayerList({
    view: mapView,
    container: 'container-div-id' 
});
```

Then, you **do not** want to add the widget to your MapView ui

```
mapView.ui.add(layerList, "bottom-right");}); // <- don't do this
```

because doing so will override the location of your widget.